Create a SwiftUI data model for WikiVoyage API Call
I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my data model. I have successfully created a network call to the WikiVoyage API. I am struggling in parsing the JSON returned from the request. I am expecting to get the HTML String in the extract key.
In Proxyman I am getting a body of the response that looks like below:
{
  "batchcomplete": true,
  "warnings": {
    "extracts": {
      "warnings": "HTML may be malformed and/or unbalanced and may omit inline images. Use at your own risk. Known problems are listed at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Extension:TextExtracts#Caveats."
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "pages": [
      {
        "pageid": 5125,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Buriram",
        "index": 1,
        "thumbnail": {
          "source": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Train_Time_Table_at_Buriram_Station..jpg/250px-Train_Time_Table_at_Buriram_Station..jpg",
          "width": 250,
          "height": 188
        },
        "extract": "HTML string here"
      }
    ]
  }
}



Here is what my data model looks like:
import Foundation

struct WikiVoyageResponse: Codable {
    let query: Query
}

struct Query: Codable {
    let pages: [Page]
}

struct Page: Codable {
    let pageid: Int
    let ns: Int
    let title: String
    let index: Int
    let thumbnail: Thumbnail
    let extract: String
}

struct Thumbnail: Codable {
    let source: String
    let width: Int
    let height: Int
}


Here is my API call:
     func getWikiData() async throws -> String {
        // This get data in a browser
        let urlString = "https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query&format=json&prop=pageimages%7Cextracts&exlimit=1&generator=prefixsearch&redirects=1&formatversion=2&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=250&pilimit=20&gpssearch=Buriram&gpslimit=1"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            throw DataError.invalidURL
            // notify user
        }
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw DataError.invalidResponse
            // notify user
        }
       
        do {
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response = try decoder.decode(WikiVoyageResponse.self, from: data)
            
            // Expecting to get html string from extract but I am getting an invalidData Error
            print("Response", response.query.pages[0].extract)
            return response.query.pages[0].extract
            
        } catch {
            throw DataError.invalidData
        }
        
    }
}


    


Instead of just throwing in your catch, print(error) and you will see why the decoding failed.

@Paulw11 This is the error I get:
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "query", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "query", intValue: nil) ("query").", underlyingError: nil))
trying to wrap my head around why query  intValue: nil

It's fine for a CodingKey to not have an intValue. Have you tried printing data as UTF8 to see if it really contains "query"?

can't seem to print data as UTF8  tried  print(data as? UTF8)
Says Cast from 'Data' to unrelated type 'UTF8' (aka 'Unicode.UTF8') always fails
If I print just data it says 1395 bytes

You can use print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)).

@xAlien95
This is what it prints:
DATA Optional("{"batchcomplete":true,"warnings":{"main":{"warnings":"Unrecognized parameters: exlimit, pilimit, piprop, pithumbsize."},"query":{"warnings":"Unrecognized value for parameter \"prop\": pageimages%7Cextracts"}}}")

@MikeHaslam that explains the JSONDecoder error: your response doesn't have a query property (query is a property in warnings). The URL you provided in your question does return a valid output, however, and I can get the HTML response as expected. Are you using a different url string?

Yes that was the problem I was dynamically adding the location and in this example I hard coded it in url. Thanks to all for the help

Glad you worked it out. I suggest not using a string with interpolation for creating your url. Start with a base url created from a simple string and then add query items

@Paulw11 I will try to add query items instead of string interpolation. Sting interpolation did wok in another call, guess I got lucky on that one

String interpolation works but it is much easier to make mistakes
